# Error when trying to make QTWebKit following Linux From Scratch

Tags: linux, qtwebkit, kde-plasma, linux-from-scratch

I'm trying to install the Plasma 5 KDE desktop and one of the required dependencies is QtWebkit, when I was trying to compile it I got this error.

```
    /sources/kde/qtwebkit-opensource-src-5.9.0-beta3/Source/JavaScriptCore/API/JSStringRef.cpp: In function ‘const JSChar* JSStringGetCharactersPtr(JSStringRef)’:
/sources/kde/qtwebkit-opensource-src-5.9.0-beta3/Source/JavaScriptCore/API/JSStringRef.cpp:86:30: error: invalid conversion from ‘const UChar* {aka const char16_t*}’ to ‘const JSChar* {aka const short unsigned int*}’ [-fpermissive]
     return string->characters();
            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
make[2]: *** [Makefile.JavaScriptCore.Target:4848: .obj/API/JSStringRef.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/sources/kde/qtwebkit-opensource-src-5.9.0-beta3/build/Source/JavaScriptCore'
make[1]: *** [Makefile.JavaScriptCore:100: sub-Target-pri-make_first-ordered] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/sources/kde/qtwebkit-opensource-src-5.9.0-beta3/build/Source/JavaScriptCore'
make: *** [Makefile:96: sub-Source-JavaScriptCore-JavaScriptCore-pro-make_first-ordered] Error 2
```

I'm using the latest beta of qtwebkit here but I get the same error when using the latest stable version. If anyone could help that would be much appreciated
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today I found a patch for this which has been added to the BLFS book this solved my problem.
This is the link:
http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/patches/blfs/svn/qtwebkit-5.8.0-icu_59-1.patch